# How to set textbox value based on the drop down box selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a requirement that based on the drop down selection I should fill data for the next input tag.

For example in drop down box, if I give values like `NETWORK1, NETWORK2, NETWORK3`. If I select NETWORK1 from dropdown textbox should fill with `127.0.0.1`, if it is NETWORK2 it will be `127.0.0.2` and so on.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
            "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body> <pre>
UserName : <input type="text" name=uname>
Password : <input type="password" name=upwd>
Confirm Password : <input type="password" name=cpwd>
Network : <select>
            <option value="N1">Network1</option>
            <option value="N2">Network2</option>
            <option value="N3">Network3</option>
     </select>
IP address : <input type="text" name=ipaddress>
</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: so, what have you tried?

Comment: i am sorry i am begginer to java i didnt know how to get that@llamerr

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: you can start reading some book or tutorial on html/js

Comment: can you suggect me any link @llamerr

Comment: search for newer resources in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/a/12329/319375

Comment: thanks for the link... but can i expect to get the code for my requirement???

Comment: I don't think so - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262103/how-to-close-please-write-code-type-questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be a lot cleaner with JQuery but in plain javascript you can do it like this:

```
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body> <pre>
UserName : <input type="text" name=uname>
Password : <input type="password" name=upwd>
Confirm Password : <input type="password" name=cpwd>
Network : <select id="network" onchange="setIP(this)">
            <option value="N1">Network1</option>
            <option value="N2">Network2</option>
            <option value="N3">Network3</option>

     </select>
IP address : <input type="text" name=ipaddress id=ipaddress>
</pre>

<script language="javascript">
    function setIP(networkSelect) {
        var val;
        switch (networkSelect.options[networkSelect.selectedIndex].value) {
                                            case 'N1': val = '127.0.0.1'; break;
                                            case 'N2': val = '127.0.0.2'; break;
                                            case 'N3': val = '127.0.0.3'; break;
                                        }
        document.getElementById('ipaddress').value = val;
    }

    setIP(document.getElementById('network'));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this gives addess in the value of option like this

```
<select id="network">
        <option value="127.0.0.1">Network1</option>
        <option value="127.0.0.2">Network2</option>
        <option value="127.0.0.3">Network3</option>
 </select>
```

IP address :

and select value as

```
    <script language="javascript">

$("#network").change(function(){
 var temp = $("#network option:selected").val();
$("#ipAddress").val(temp);
 });
  </script>
```

and add header file of jquery

Comment: Thanks for the info @Asad Sheikh